# Excel - Group Similar, but Hide Duplicate Rows

Tags: excel

I'm convinced I'm missing something simple... Here's the short and simple.  I have a spreadsheet that looks something like this:

```
Excel
Line   ID    Name    Value 1    Value 2
1      001   Bob     123        456
2      002   Bob     234        567
3      003   Bob     345        678
4      004   Jim     abc        def
5      005   Jim     bcd        efg
6      006   Jim     cde        fgh
```

And I'm looking for an end result like this:

```
Excel
Line   ID    Name    Value 1    Value 2
1+     001   Bob     123        456
4+     004   Jim     abc        def
```

In my result, I would like to sort by a text value in a column ("name"), and hide each duplicate row, regardless if the other columns have different information.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to expand "Bob" by clicking on something.

I think I've seen this done before, but I can't figure how to do it.

Thoughts?

Comment: When you say *hide each duplicate row*, you mean only in the 'name' column, correct, since you don't care *if the other columns have different information*?

Comment: Brian - Yes, the rest of the columns may have differing information, but I only care that they're grouped by "name".  If "name" is duplicate, then hide that entire row.

Comment: What about @rohrl77's idea? I think it is the easiest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the layout and the data processed the way you want using a Pivot Table. Apply the Pivot Table and drag the Name Field in to the Row Section. It will automatically be grouped.

Comment: PivotTable is the way to go for the kind of interactive functionality you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

My first thoughts would be to write a VBA macro.

Step 1, sort the data to ensure your "keys" are contiguous - i.e. sort by the "Name" column.

Step 2, then iterate over the data range rows, keeping track of when the current block starts and noticing when it ends - at that point you can then programmatically group the rows in the VBA code.

The macro recorder is probably your friend, here, as it will give you some good skeleton functions to achieve each step.

That gives you the grouping functionality you want.

If you're happy with just a list of uniques, and having a table with the first entry of each unique "Name", and really don't want to delve into VBA, you can first generate a list of unique Names in a separate column, and then do a VLOOKUP on that to replicate the original table. You can get the unique names via a pivot table, or use the Advanced data filter (see Data Ribbon) to copy unique records from the list to a separate location.

Answer (score 0):

This question is quite old, but as an extra idea, the question could also be solved using [Excel's outlining](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/outline-group-data-in-a-worksheet-08ce98c4-0063-4d42-8ac7-8278c49e9aff) features.